# Is it possible to perform API calls from Share extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, api

I am not sure whether it's possible or not but I want to perform GET API call from share extension and display result on it.

Not sure how Whatsapp is performing POST call from share extension. Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: The share extension will have a class and its method will be executed so you can easily call your web service, Also for reference, you can see the Google Drive.

Comment: I think you should use singleton class pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got working solution using NSURLSession, I tried Alamofire but it was not working. Thanks [Salman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5657569/salman-ghumsani) for your suggestion. :)

I think **Alamofire** is not available because in my pod file I have not set target to extension's target